# Как отсортировать TreeView по имени?

Tags: c#, wpf, сортировка, treeview

```
                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>

                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding collection_node}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name_}">
                                    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>

                                    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeView>

public class Node
    {
        public string name_ { get; set; }
```

Comment: или конвертер написать как вариант http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722835/how-to-sort-treeview-items-using-sortdescriptions-in-xaml или расширить observableCollection. Возможно получится вариант подключить itemsource через ICollectionView и var desc = new SortDescription(MyProp, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
         myCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(desc);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
collection_node = new ObservableCollection(
    collection_node.OrderBy(n => n.Name)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Good example how to use sort.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CollectionView-Tips-MVVM-d6ebb4a7#content

Comment: Полагаю, это скорее дополнение к вашему предыдущему ответу, чем новый, правильно?

Comment: у каждого решения есть много варянтов.Выбирать вам каким воспользоваться

Comment: Полностью с вами согласен. Но, повторюсь, разве вы не считаете, что ссылка скорее дополняет ваш предыдущий ответ, чем является новым?

Comment: Это 2 разных подхода.Все зависит от того что нужно в результате сделать.1 решение это так по быстрому.2 это подход г генерному решению проблемы

Comment: Наверное, не совсем точно выразился. Вы не находите, что одной ссылки не достаточно для ответа?

Comment: У меня к вам вопрос.Завтра вам понадобиться сделать 10 новых фильтров.Вы 10 раз сделаете новую ObservableCollection?

Comment: 1 решение это решение частного случая.1 раз отсортировал и забыл.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49845/discussion-between-foggy-finder-and-leonid-koyler).

Comment: Лучше объединить два ответа в один. Подробнее [тут](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2350/) и [тут](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3556/)